# Store data in hdfs datanodes - kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hdfs

i have i file "test.txt",located in /home/kmaster

[image: here's the file]

when i try to use

```
hdfs dfs -put path-myfile hdfs://namenodeadress:8020/.., i get
```

this results

[image: no such file or directory]

Comment: HDFS isn't really a service that should be ran in Kubernetes (my opinion). It is not "cloud native". You should try [Ozone](https://ozone.apache.org/) or MinIO for Hadoop-compatible storage (assuming you actually need it)

Comment: but in this project, they need hdfs for storing data

Comment: That's all good and fine, but is it required to be running in Kubernetes? Managing the persistent volumes will be a pain if so... Also, what's your exact question? You'd run `hdfs put file hdfs://namenode-address:8020/some-path` to upload data... Running on kubernetes doesn't change that

Comment: I need to store my data in my cluster's datanode. In this command "hdfs put file hdfs://namenode-address:8020/some-path" the path that i'll add is the path of my file right?

Comment: `file` is a local path. The path at the end is the destination

Comment: when i add the path of my local file ( i'm sure of the path ), the execution give me an error that said: /home/user/..(local path ) no such file or directory

Comment: Once you `kubectl exec`, you are in a **separate filesystem**. Apparently you have no mounts for `/home/kmaster`. For example, `hdfs dfs -put /opt/hadoop-2.7.7/conf/hdfs-site.xml ...` should work fine... Also, you should use Kubernetes service names rather than IP's for the namenode address

Comment: yes you're right. Is there a way to have mounts for /home/kmaster ?

Comment: Sure. Use volumes on your pods https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/